# How to execute a stored procedure via odbc using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, odbc, sap-ase

How to execute a stored procedure via odbc using c#?

I want to execute it without the risk of a sql injection, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
using (OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText //your store procedure name;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Paremeters.Add("@yourParameter", OdbcType.NChar, 50).Value = yourParameter

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    connection.Open();    
    using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso I think this part `command.Paremeters.Add("@yourParameter", OdbcType.NChar, 50).Value = yourParameter` needs to be in two lines, one to add the parameter and another to set the value.

Comment: aF is right, I needed to change that but the rest worked! Thanks Massi